# Xamarin monotouch adding license

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I've installed monotouch, monodevelop trial version on my Mac.
I now have a license (both serial key and a file), and I wonder how to I add the license to monotouch and monodeveloper so that I can run my apps on my iPhone?

Thnx!!

Comment: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Getting_Started/Installation#Step_4_-_Activating_the_Installation

Answer (score 1):

You should contact support@xamarin.com for any issues related to activation and/or installation.